# Does the law of reciprocity hold true for the phase response of an antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, electromagnetism, transfer-function, radio

I know that an antennas spectral transfer function should be the same in both transmit and receive due to the law of reciprocity, however does this law hold true for the phase response (AKA phase transfer function) of an antenna?

Interested in both what is expected based on theory and  what is actually observed in real life. I can't find much literature on the phase transfer function of an antenna.

Comment: Please define this: *phase transfer function of an antenna*

Comment: yes, gain and phase, hardly worth a full answer, so a comment

Comment: @Neil_UK don't suppose you have a reference to support that? As this paper seems to suggest to me a phase change in the case of Transmit vs Receive: https://www.sic.rma.ac.be/~scheers/Papers/chapter4.pdf

Comment: @Christian what part of that paper (page number and phrase required) 'seems to suggest a phase change between tx and rx'? It's too long for me to want to flog through it all while attempting to read your mind.

Comment: @Neil_UK I guess to summarise, the fact that the impulse response function of the transmitted waveform is the differential of the impulse response function of the received waveform, suggesting a 90 degree phase shift between the two. Derived in sections 4.3.1 to 4.4.2

Comment: @Christian Section 4.3.3 says ratio of Efield to terminal voltage depends on wavelength. However, Efield depends on wavelength for a given power, so we just watched the magician put a rabbit into the hat, before withdrawing it. Do take care around the assumptions and approximations like effective source position. Remember that if a passive lossless component 'knows' which way the power is flowing by having different gain in the different directions, then you could build an over unity device. Active components of course don't have this constraint.

Comment: @Neil_UK I agree with you about it not being possible to have different gain in different directions, however I also agree with the conclusions of the paper which show the measured waveform on Rx being (similar) to a differential of the injected pulse on Tx. Which is how I ended up at the idea, that perhaps it is the phase relationship that doesn't obey reciprocity in the same way. Apologies I'm not too sure where you are going with the first part of the previous comment.